# How to verify the running time of an algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I made coded the global alignment algorithm using affine gap cost. The algorithm running time in big-O notation is O(n^2). However, my teacher in the class said that in order to verify the running time one has to divide the running time with n^2 where n is the length of the sequence (using sequences of different lengths[image]). And if (n,R(n)/n^2) is below a horizontal line then the running time is verified. I couldn't really understand what that meant. I plotted R(n)/n^2 using sequences of different lengths. And it worked. I had fluctuations in the beginning but then the fluctuations went away (you can see this in the image too). The sequences I used were from 1000 bases long to 10,000 bases long.
Can someone how R(n)/n^2 verifies the running time? I've tried looking on the internet but couldn't find a possible answer. Forgive me, if my question is too simple. I do not have a computer science background.

Comment: What you are doing is normalizing the data, so that if it is indeed O(n^2) then the output should be constant. Same if you have O(n) then you do R(n)/n to see if it is really linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) is defined as the set of functions *R*(*n*) such that, for some constant *c*, *R*(*n*) ≤ *cn*<sup>2</sup> for all sufficiently large *n*.

That inequality is equivalent to <sup>*R*(*n*)</sup>/<sub>*n*<sup>2</sup></sub> ≤ *c*.

So your teacher is suggesting that you plot <sup>*R*(*n*)</sup>/<sub>*n*<sup>2</sup></sub> to see that, for sufficiently large *n*, you get (roughly) a constant *c*.

Note that this plot is not a formal proof. It's just a helpful visualization.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what it means.

Answer (score 2):

If we say an algorithm is in O(n²), we actually mean the number of steps needed to run the algorithm as a **function of input size n** is in O(n²).

When we say a function is in O(n²), we actually mean there is a positive constant `c` so that `f(n) < c * n²` for big input sizes n.

This is equivalent to saying: there is a positive constant `c` so that `c > f(n) / n²` for big input sizes n.

You already noticed that your graph above converges towards a constant value. This is your `c`.

Of course, the number of steps needed to run an algorithm [depend on the machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_model) you use.

Comment: Thank you your answer has helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Some maths.  (Sorry, but you do need a bit of maths to really understand this.)

The notation `f(n)` is `O(n^2)` means that:

> 1) define g(n) = f(n) / n<sup>2</sup>
>
> 2) the limit as N tends to infinity of g(n) is C, where C is some constant

Intuitively, that says the `g(n)` function gets closer and closer to `C` as `n` gets larger and larger.  A mathematician would say that it "converges" to `C`.

(Actually, the maths is a bit more complicated than that, but I'm very rusty.  And I'm trying to keep this simple.)

What your graph is doing to *demonstrating* that g(n) does actually converge.  And the C value is that value on your Y-axis that corresponds to the straight line that your graph is approaching ... as the value on the X-axis goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

To explain it even simpler: An algorithm in O(n²) is like a quadratic function. You can always divide a quadratic function by a function of the form a * b² to get a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

The running time being O(n^2) means there will always exist 2 real positive numbers **b** and **n0** such that, for every **n >= n0**,

R(n) <= b*(n^2), where R(n) is the running time function.

In other words, the running time stays lower than a function of the form b*(n^2).

---

If you take that inequality and divide everything by (n^2), you get:

R(n)/(n^2) <= b

and the Big O definition still applies.

So as long as R(n)/(n^2) stays below **b** for **n >= n0**, then R(n) is O(n^2). Again, in other words, this means staying below the constant function **b** (horizontal line).

What you are doing is plotting R(n)/n^2 and checking if the graph stabilizes horizontally, for sufficiently high **n**.

This is easier than plotting R(n) and trying to identify if the graph is approximately a quadratic function (quadratic functions are quite similar to cubic and higher order polynomials, don't you agree?). If R(n) was actually O(n^3), R(n)/(n^2) would give you a crescent function, and you'd verify that in your graph.